# How do I store Information when I run the program

Tags: python

How do I store Information in python when I run it?

Here is the code:

```
list = [""]
plist = raw_input("What do you want to append: ")
list.append(plist)
print list
```

When it's run:

```
What do you want to append: Hello
Hello
```

Now let's say I left to go eat then I come back, I run the program:

```
What do you want to append: People
People
```

The problem is that the program didn't store the word Hello and kept People. How do I make python store all the information I write in the raw_input store it?

Comment: You need to learn about files.  You can write your data to a file.  You may want to use the popular json format.  Search for json.dumps and files in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make information persistent across executions, you should save it to a file. This is standard with programming languages - variables are stored in the memory (RAM), and are reset on each execution.

On top of that, in your example, you are explicitly creating an empty list to append to. To append to a list you made earlier, save that list into a file and make the list from the content of that file.

```
# This opens the file and reads each line into the list, then closes it
file=open('listfile.txt','r')
list = file.readlines()
file.close()

plist = raw_input("What do you want to append: ")
list.append(plist)

# This opens the file, writes each item in the list to a line and then closes it    
file=open('listfile.txt','w')
for item in list:
    file.write(str(item))
file.close()

print (list)
```

Comment: What does the 'r' and 'w' mean?

Comment: Do I have to use file = open(ect) or can I change the name file to filename?

Comment: @Supercolbat That can be any valid variable name

Answer (score 1):

When you restart the program, all of the variables from the previous program are dumped or 'forgotten' by Python. If you want the program to keep asking what word you want to append until you quit, you can use a `for` loop or `while` loop. For example, you could just write:

```
for i in range(10):
     plist = raw_input("What do you want to append: ")
     list.append(plist)
     print(list)
```

This would allow you to enter 10 words, and `list` would have all of them. However, if you want to close the program and restart it and have all the data from the last time you ran it, you should write it in an external file, as the others have answered!